# sending email using java code through smtp

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm getting this below error and timeout exception.

enter code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL true
    Exceptioninthread"main"java.lang.RuntimeException:com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,port:smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1.

Comment: Post the stack trace, the code that produces it, etc to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Btw, you are using code snippet to write the plain English and vice versa

Comment: @Aniket sahrawat 
Properties props = new Properties();  
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host); 
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
   props.put("mail.debug", "true");

Comment: host="smtp.gmail.com";  port=:587";

Comment: okay.i will edit it.

Comment: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; like this i'm getting.

Comment: are you doing an authentication (with a username and password?)

Comment: yes..Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
   }
  });
 @Maurice perry

Comment: You have include host, port, SSL, user and password

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  //String host="localhost";
  //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  //props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");//587
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  //System.out.println("1");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
         //System.out.println("2");

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

         //System.out.println("3");

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        // System.out.println("4");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        // System.out.println("5");

        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        //System.out.println("sent successfully...");
    }
    catch (AddressException ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

calling above method and pass these parameters to the method

```
private static String USER_NAME = "xxxx";  // username "@gmail.com")
private static String PASSWORD = "xxxx"; // password
private static String RECIPIENT = "xxx@gmail.com";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String from = USER_NAME;
    String pass = PASSWORD;
    String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
    String subject = "Java send mail example";
    String body = "Welcome to JavaMail!";

    sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
}
```

And i used following jar files ,

```
java-mail-1.4.4
javamail-smtp-1.4.2
pop3
mail-6.0.0-sources
```

Comment: So the property "mail.smtp.ssl.trust" would make all the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore most of the other answers and comments, which are wrong or irrelevant.  Many of them include these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Your original code was fine.

See the [JavaMail FAQ for GMail instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).

Most likely you can't connect because there is some firewall preventing direct access.  The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

If you can't connect directly and need to connect through a proxy server, the [JavaMail FAQ also covers that](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).